# i want to create a filter for a search, how can i do this that will not involve a huge switch case statement?

Tags: android, refactoring, switch-statement

Like the title says, i got a list of something that i want to use a filter on with 7 options.

If i want to put all those options in a case, it will take, let me see 7*6*5*4*3*2*1 meaning 5040 possiblities. Right?

So how can i make it so, that it is not this big of a switch statement?

I have looked arround on google but coudnt find any solution.
like:[android multiple options case](https://www.google.nl/search?q=android%20multiple%20options%20case&rlz=1C1CHFX_nlNL531NL531&oq=android%20multiple%20options%20case&aqs=chrome..69i57.14418j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8), [android filter search listview](https://www.google.nl/search?q=android+filter+search+listview&rlz=1C1CHFX_nlNL531NL531&oq=android+filter+search+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.12243j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I would put all the data in an SQLite Database and use `where` clauses.

Answer (score 1):

You want to apply each option in turn to the filtered list you get.
So if 1st option is on, get a new list that has been filtered by option 1.
Then if 2nd option is on, filter the filtered list from option 1 with option 2. And so on and so forth.

You'll end up with 7 ifs (1 for each option) and you should just keep filtering the list you get back.

Comment: this seems very simple... i might give this a try ty:)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a switch statement for each options you can simply check for first option if it is not upto mark no need to check for others options.
Simillarly if first option is fullfilling the condition it will not check for your first and goes to second option if it is not fullfilling the condition then no need to check for rest of the options and so on...

Comment: well this will not work as there are more options to use as a filter.

Answer (score 0):

try this way : 
 extend Filterable:

```
  @Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            modelValues = (ArrayList<String>) results.values; // has

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            List<Model> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<Model>();

            if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<Model>(modelValues); // saves

            }

            /********
             * 
             * If constraint(CharSequence that is received) is null returns
             * the mOriginalValues(Original) values else does the Filtering
             * and returns FilteredArrList(Filtered)
             * 
             ********/
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                // set the Original result to return
                results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                results.values = mOriginalValues;
            } else {
                Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase(locale);
                for (String model : mOriginalValues) {


                    String data =model;
                    if (data.toLowerCase(locale).contains("7".toString())||data.toLowerCase(locale).contains("6".toString())||data.toLowerCase(locale).contains("5".toString())||data.toLowerCase(locale).contains("4".toString())) {

                        FilteredArrList.add(modelMyMall);
                    }
                }
                // set the Filtered result to return
                results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                results.values = FilteredArrList;

            }
            return results;
        }
    };
    return filter;
}
```

Comment: could you add some explaining with this, because i dont get it, what it does.

Answer (score 0):

use this way :

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] 
                              {"7", "6","3", "5"})); //7*6*5*$*3*2*1
       System.out.println("List Before: " + list);
    for (Iterator<String> it=list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
if (!it.next().contains("How"))
    it.remove(); // NOTE: Iterator's remove method, not ArrayList's, is used.
  }
    System.out.println("List After: " + list);
```